# singleton class returning null pointer exception in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello in the below code calling from pesnative to pesmanager created singleton instance in pesmanager but it is giving null pointer exception.

PESNative.java:

```
this.pesBleDevice = PesBleDevice.getInstance(webView,context,bleStatus);
```

```
pesManager.registrationBLECommand();
```

PesManager.java:

`

```
private static PesManager instance;
public static PesManager getInstance(CordovaWebView webVw) {
        if (instance == null) {
            webView = webVw;
            deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
            instance = new PesManager();
            bluetoothDevices = new HashMap<>();
        }
        return instance;
    }
public void registrationBLECommand() {
        pesDevice.registrationBLECommand();
    }`
```

PesbleDevice.java:

```
`public void registrationBLECommand() {
        Log.d("jyothi", String.valueOf(bluetoothGatt));
        if (bluetoothGatt != null){
            getRegistartionBLE(bluetoothGatt);
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(activity,"gatt null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }`
```

Hello In the above calling registation command from one class to another getting null pointer exception .

From one class to another class app crash with reporting as null pointer

Comment: Do you set `pesDevice` anywhere?

Comment: @TheLibrarian yes I set in pesNative class

Comment: From the code you have provided there is no way to tell that it couldn't be null. What object does the error mention?

Comment: calling from pesDevice.registrationBLECommand(); executing else condition

Comment: can you give me the chat access?